# printf statements not showing up

Tags: visual-c++, printf

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 and trying to debug someone else's program. I tried to use printf statements but for some reason, these statements are not shown on the screen as the program runs. I am able to use fprintf to print these statements to file, but this is useless when the program crashes in the middle of execution, as the file would be empty then.

How can I force some output to screen?

Comment: Is this project a console application or a GUI one? `printf` doesn't work unless a Console window is created.

Comment: It's a console application. Nothing shows up on the MS-DOS/cmd screen.

Comment: Try using `fprintf()` with `stderr`.

Comment: Using the debugger is invaluable when a program crashes! When a program crashes it should actually be you first reaction to run it in the debugger. It will show you _where_ it crashes, show a stack trace so you know the function call stack, as well as let you examine variables to help you understand why it might have crashed. As for the output of `printf` not showing, add a newline after the text, or call `fflush(stdout)` to flush the output.

Comment: Also, as you have two problems you should probably have posted this as two questions: One for the output problem (which would have been closed as a duplicate); And one for the crashing problem, together with relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

To force output to the screen, please see the first section below.  The second and third options below are also good for debugging program crashes like these.

**Using printf with fflush (refinement of Vishal Kumar's answer)**

Vishal Kumar's answer worked for me, but I had to do a little research to find out how to use fflush.  I had a problem where my program was crashing "in the middle" of a printf statement which did not make sense.  Here is my refinement of his answer.  In cases where a debugger is difficult to use (e.g. multithreading), you can use fflush after every printf (or fprintf) statement.  For example, "pepper your code" with:

```
... // code
printf("Part 1 executed successfully");
fflush(stdout); // flushes the stdout buffer
... // further code
printf("Part 2 executed successfully");
fflush(stdout);
... // repeat as necessary
```

Run, observe the output, and put more print statements between the last statement that prints, and the first statement that doesn't print, until you isolate the problem.

**Debugger**

If you are able to use a debugger, it is a more efficient choice than peppering your code with output statements as described above, but there are cases where you have to resort to that.

**Valgrind**

If you are using Linux (which I gather you are not because it is in MS Visual C++), valgrind is another option to see where your code is crashing (and for detecting memory leaks).  If your code is compiled for debug, if your program is called "myProgram", you can just call from the terminal window as follows:

```
valgrind myProgram
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped in getting the print statements visible at terminal. Forcing output to the screen sometimes makes our life easy in terms of fixing broken code.

Comment: @Sarvesh Pandey Glad it was useful!